# Does specifying criteria switch the location provider in Android?

Tags: android, location, switching, location-provider

I want that the application should switch between GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER automatically. At present, I specify the providers in the program, so, if I specify criteria and set the locationlistener with that, then will it switch automatically to GPS_PROVIDER automatically whenever available?

For example, when the app started and listener was set at that time GPS_PROVIDER was not available or was not receiving location updates, but after some time it started receiving location updates then will the app automatically get the data from GPS_PROVIDER?

Otherwise, what is the best way of switching between the providers?

Just to add one more thing, the application will call requestLocationUpdates() only once in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify your onLocationChanged method like,

```
   @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){   
    Log.e("OnLocationChange Latitude",""+location.getLatitude());
            Log.e("OnLocationChange Longitude",""+location.getLongitude());

}
}
```

now these lat,long are given by gps provider. and for your other question I think you tested the application on emulator.

Comment: What I want to know is will criteria automatically switch between providers or not?

Comment: hope this [link](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslocationmaps/226-android-location-providers-gps-network-passive) will help you.

Comment: Specifying criteria do not changes the litener automatically.